# Sql error while using "LIMIT".

Tags: php, sql, limit, sql-like

I'm getting error "`Undeclared variable: $start`" while using the SQL query below.

```
<?php
  if($Spage == ""){
     $Spage = "1";
  }
  $Sper_page = "5"; 
  $start = ($Spage-1)*$Sper_page;
  $sResults = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty("SELECT * FROM experts WHERE exp_process LIKE '%".$process."%' AND exp_machinaries like '%".$machineCat."%' AND exp_country = '". $country."' 'LIMIT $start, $Sper_page'");
?>
```

Comment: LIMIT but no ORDER BY? Kinda odd.

Comment: @jarlh - Depends on if the table is large or small - or if he wants ordered by default primary key. Order By is not necessary and lack of it is not really that odd depending on use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed your single quotes. Should be

```
$sResults = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty("SELECT * FROM experts WHERE exp_process LIKE '%".$process."%' AND exp_machinaries like '%".$machineCat."%' AND exp_country = '". $country."' LIMIT $start, $Sper_page");
```

And cleaning up the query a bit:

```
$sResults = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty("SELECT * FROM experts WHERE exp_process LIKE '%$process%' AND exp_machinaries like '%$machineCat%' AND exp_country = '$country' LIMIT $start, $Sper_page");
```

Next step to remove would be to use prepared statements and bind these parameters in

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (another way in setting Limit and Offset)

```
<?php
  if($Spage == ""){
     $Spage = "1";
  }
  $Sper_page = "5"; 
  $start = ($Spage-1)*$Sper_page;
  $sResults = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty("SELECT * FROM experts WHERE exp_process LIKE '%".$process."%' AND exp_machinaries like '%".$machineCat."%' AND exp_country = '". $country."'LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $start'");
?>
```

And BTW you *misplaced* a single quote near LIMIT.

Comment: Another member of the _try this club_ Please explain WHY we should try this. _Try this answers_ get put in the low quality queue and are often deleted

Comment: Better, but you only get a half corona

Comment: @Hard Spocker I tried this code but getting error "Undeclared variable OFFSET"

Answer (score 0):

You left out a space between  LIMIT and '.
It must've been

```
$country."' '   LIMIT  .  ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the creation of your query much too complicated and therefore missing some simple errors. Remember that when you use double quoutes `"` in PHP it will expand `$variables` into the string for you.

So a simpler and easier to read and therefore debug method would be this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM experts 
        WHERE exp_process LIKE '%$process%' 
          AND exp_machinaries like '%$machineCat%' 
          AND exp_country = '$country' 
        LIMIT $start, $Sper_page";

$sResults = $oCon->dbFetchSmarty($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

For best solution to check query is in phpmyadmin. You just echo query and copy/past query section into phpmyadmin. so it will give a proper guidance for your structure of query or any error for same.